# ASP.NET generate some API calls without token

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, oauth

I'm working on a ASP.NET API project that uses OAuth. The authentication uses a CustomJWTFormat. And it has StateYourBusiness to authorize logged in users to different resources. However, I can't find a way to have some API calls be called without using a token. I hope to put some pictures on the homepage before logging in. Currently, these pictures are accessed by an API controller but that would need a token. Is there a way to make some API calls without token?

Comment: just add the [AllowAnonymous] attribute to the controller method

Comment: If you show some code, i'm sure someone can demonstrate the [AllowAnonymous] decorator on your controller method.

Comment: Thank you Johnny! It works!

Comment: It has worked, thank you mjw!